# R - Count number of rows based on specific matching criteria

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that I wish to, upon matching a set criteria (match variable), in a separate column count 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 etc.... After the condition is met, it shall continue to count until the next match appears.

if i set:

match <- <-1.0

The below data.frame is an example of the output:

```
    roll.z.score.n3 sig.count    
1           NA          0          
2           NA          0          
3   -1.135974424        1          
4   0.193311168         2          
5   0.714285714         3          
6   -1.148753543        4          
7   -0.942160394        5          
8   0.695763683         6          
9   1.140646864         7          
10  0.985196899         8          
11  -0.768766574        1          
12  -1.011293858        2          
13  -0.516703612        3          
14  -1.120897077        4          
15  1.091089451         5          
16  0.968364052         6          
17  0.872871561         7          
18  1.099524999         8          
19  0.918397948         9
```

on row 3 we have a match below -1.0. So the count beings, and it continues until the next match below -1.0 on line 11. The count then begins... and it would continue to do so until the next match below -1.0.

Any assistance is appreciated!

EDIT: In response to baptise

```
set.seed(123)
new.df$sig_long <- runif(13787,2,1)
cbind(new.df$sig_long, n = do.call(c, lapply(rle(new.df$sig_long < -1)[["lengths"]], seq_len)))
```

> cbind(new.df$sig_long, n = do.call(c, lapply(rle(new.df$sig_long < -1)[["lengths"]], seq_len)))
>   Error in do.call(c, lapply(rle(new.df$sig_long < -1)[["lengths"]], seq_len)) : 
>     'what' must be a function or character string

Answer (score 0):

something like this perhaps,

```
set.seed(123)
x <- runif(20,-2,1)
cbind(x, n = do.call(c, lapply(rle(x < -1)[["lengths"]], seq_len)))
```

Comment: Does the above place the 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc on each row of the time series as the above? I thought rle finds the longest length? seq_along does a count... i just need it to start the count on first match <-1.0 and then continue the count until the next <-1.0

Comment: I am getting the error as my edit in the post.... i would accept the answer if it had worked. Do you know what im doing wrong?